# Select tag html problems

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

Okay, I am trying to place a font-awesome icon in my select tag because I can't leave the default one due to Safari behavior. The default one makes me take off the style with:

```
-webkit-appearance:none;
```

The problem is that this removes the select arrows too. That's why I am trying with font-awesome. The thing is I just can't put my font-awesome icon inside my select box at all.

Does anybody can help?

Here's my code:

```css
select {
  color: #9b9b9b;
  border: 1px solid #9b9b9b;
  font-family: SF-UI-Text-Regular;
  background-color: white;
  background: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  font-size: 11px;
  letter-spacing: 2.4px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 90%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fff;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 27px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s ease-out;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-stretch: normal;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-wvfXpqpZZVQGK6TAh5PVlGOfQNHSoD2xbE+QkPxCAFlNEevoEH3Sl0sibVcOQVnN" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="col-md-12">
  <input placeholder="E-mail" class="input-field" name="email" required type="email" >
  <i class="fa fa-caret-down" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  <select class="col-md-12 fix-padding fa-select" required name="option">
    <option value="" disabled selected>Budget</option>
    <option value="$25,000 to $50,000">$25,000 to $50,000</option>
    <option value="$50,000 to $100,000">$50,000 to $100,000</option>
    <option value="$100,000 to $200,000">$100,000 to $200,000</option>
    <option value="Over $200,000">Over $200,000</option>
    <option value="Undefined">Undefined</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: None of your CSS is applied to the font awesome icon, just to the `select` element. you'll need to add some code for the `.fa-caret-down`. Also, if the email text input is not part of the question, please remove it from your example.

Comment: Styling `select`'s are always a problem and you really don't have that much freedom. The common solution to have a custom styled `select` with a custom arrow is to not use a `select` at all and use other HTML elements (like `div`'s and `ul`'s to make a fake select). This is a lot of work which is why there are many javascript plugins that do just this... like [Select2](https://select2.github.io/). I would recommend using one of these plugins if you want a custom styled `select`

Comment: I found this JSBin that helps me! But i will have a look at Select2! thanks @zgood  http://jsbin.com/aniyu4/2440/edit?html,css,output